# I get this error when trying to use Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, odata, citrix

I am trying to pull data from Citrix's Odata API on PowerShell, just some users and their sessions' log in and log off times.

It gives me the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : An error occurred while processing this request.
The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. 
Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.
```

on the following line of code:

```
$userdata = Invoke-RestMethod -uri "http://localhost/Citrix/Monitor/Odata/v1/Data/Users" -Credential $cred
```

No where on the script I am using any "First" method. I would greatly appreciate your help with this, thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a LINQ error emitted by the REST service; without knowing the service, there are two possibilities: it's either an outright bug in the service, or missing or invalid input is being handled ungracefully.

Comment: seems like your missing some required information/headers, see example here.. it might help you https://www.mycugc.org/blogs/eltjo-van-gulik/2019/01/16/blog-monitoring-citrix-cloud-with-odata-and-powers